# Respostas Ctrl c+Ctrl v

Tags: suporte

Qual procedimento devemos tomar ao notar que um usuário discararamente(suposição) usou <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> e <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> na resposta de outro usuário?

Por exemplo nesta pergunta: [Calculadora em php](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/11824/calculadora-em-php/11832#11832)

[Resposta 1](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/11832/35406): respondida 4/04/14 às 18:12

[Resposta 2](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/74194/35406): respondida 12/07/15 às 13:41

Comment: O engraçado é que ficou mais de ano assim e eu nem reparei.

Comment: @Bacco Pra falar a verdade, eu nem sei como fui parar lá naquela questão (talvez olhando suas respostas, eu digo talvez). Mas ai reparei que estava muito igual, porém sem o comentário inicial. Ai não soube o que fazer e fiz a pergunta aqui. =)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Em casos desses podes criar uma *flag*, sinalizar, para um moderador agir. É sempre bom que casos destes sejam sinalizados para serem corrigidos.

Neste caso [é mesmo cópia integral](https://www.diffchecker.com/fGAkGhUw) e por isso vou deixar um comentário lá e simplesmente apagar.

Comment: Em outros casos, já vi usuários mudando nomes de variáveis e inserindo com resposta diferente. Pensando bem, se a variável está com nome diferente, a resposta já não é a mesma, porém segue o mesmo sentido. Sinceramente, deixei passar por não saber agir nessa  determinada situação.

Comment: @seamusd mudar nomes de variáveis soa-me a esconder a cópia, nesse caso é igual ou pior...

Comment: Você apagou a resposta e minha pergunta se tornou invalida por não ter informações suficiente para comprovar o ocorrido. Acha que eu devo apagar a pergunta ou deve permanecer assim, apesar de já ter respondido sobre o procedimento?

Comment: @seamusd utilizadores com mais reputação podem ver perguntas apagadas. Para além disso, na minha resposta tem um link com a comparação de conteúdos. Podes deixar ficar a pergunta aqui.